# Cardinality of Dedekind Completion of Hyperreals

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, model-theory

Let $^*\mathbb{R}$ denote the hyperreal field constructed as an ultra power of $\mathbb{R}$. At the expense of losing the field properties, we may take the Dedekind completion of $^*\mathbb{R}$ to get a new totally ordered set. Denote the Dedekind completion by $\overline{^*\mathbb{R}}$.

I’m curious what the cardinality of $\overline{^*\mathbb{R}}$ is. It is easy to see that $|^*\mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{R}|$ from the ultra power construction. Since $^*\mathbb{R}$ is dense in $\overline{^*\mathbb{R}}$, it follows that $|\mathbb{R}| \leq |\overline{^*\mathbb{R}}| \leq 2^{|\mathbb{R}|}$.

There are some intuitive arguments I can make for $|\overline{^*\mathbb{R}}|$ living at either extreme. I have thus far been unsuccessful in proving anything of substance though.

Comment: I suspect it may be undecidable in ZFC.  I suggest cross-posting this in MathOverload where the professionals are.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Mind telling me why you have that suspicion? The idea crossed my mind, but my intuition is telling me it should (provably) live at one of the extremes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a partial answer.

For any infinite cardinal $\kappa$, we write $\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)$ for the supremum, over all linear orders $X$ of size $\kappa$, of the cardinality of the set of Dedekind cuts in $X$. We always have $\kappa<\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)\leq 2^\kappa$.

Now suppose $S$ is a [saturated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturated_model) dense linear order of cardinality $\kappa$. I claim that $S$ has the maximal number of Dedekind cuts, i.e., the number of Dedekind cuts in $S$ is $\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)$.

Since $\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)$ is defined as a supremum, and $\kappa<\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)$, it suffices to show that for any $\lambda$ with $\kappa<\lambda\leq \mathrm{ded}(\kappa)$, if there is a linear order $X$ with $\lambda$-many Dedekind cuts, then $S$ has at least $\lambda$-many Dedekind cuts.

Now since $S$ is a saturated dense linear order and $|X|\leq |S|$, there is an order embedding $e\colon X\to S$. For each Dedekind cut $(L,R)$ in $X$, $(e(L),e(R))$ generates a Dedekind cut in $S$, unless it is "filled", i.e., there are elements of $S$ between $e(L)$ and $e(R)$. But since $|S| = \kappa$, at most $\kappa$-many of the images of the cuts in $X$ are filled in $S$. Since $\lambda>\kappa$, $\lambda$-many cuts in $X$ have images that are cuts in $S$. This completes the proof that $S$ has $\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)$-many Dedekind cuts.

---

How is this relevant to the hyperreals? Let $^*\mathbb{R}$ be an ultrapower of $\mathbb{R}$ by a non-principal ultrafilter on $\omega$. Then $^*\mathbb{R}$ is $\aleph_1$-saturated. If we assume CH, $|^*\mathbb{R}| = \aleph_1$, so the underlying linear order of $^*\mathbb{R}$ is $\aleph_1$-saturated and dense. By the result above, the number of Dedekind cuts in $^*\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathrm{ded}(\aleph_1)>\aleph_1$.

Thus, **assuming CH**, $|\overline{^*\mathbb{R}}|>\aleph_1$. And if we also assume $2^{\aleph_1} = \aleph_2$, then $|\overline{^*\mathbb{R}}|\leq 2^{|\mathbb{R}|} = \aleph_2$, so we obtain that $|\overline{^*\mathbb{R}}| = \aleph_2 = 2^{|\mathbb{R}|}$.

I suspect it is consistent that CH holds but $\mathrm{ded}(\aleph_1)<2^{\aleph_1}$ (can anyone confirm?). If so, then there is a model of ZFC in which $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1 < \mathrm{ded}(\aleph_1) < 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$, so $|\mathbb{R}| <|\overline{^*\mathbb{R}}| < 2^{|\mathbb{R}|}$.

I have no idea what happens if CH fails. It seems likely that without CH, the cardinality of $\overline{^*\mathbb{R}}$ depends on the ultrafilter you use to take the ultrapower.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you so much for the thoughtful reply! I’m going to leave the question open for now to see if anyone has any comments on the possibility of CH + ded$(\aleph_1) < 2^{\aleph_1}$ and the $\neg$CH case.

Comment: One clarifying question. Why is it obvious that $\kappa < \text{ded}(\kappa)$?

Comment: @Joe It's not obvious, but it's a theorem. Here's a proof sketch: let $\lambda$ be the least cardinal such that $2^\lambda > \kappa$, and note $\lambda\leq \kappa$. Consider the complete binary tree of height $\lambda$: $2^{<\lambda}$ ordered "left-to-right". The tree has $\leq\kappa$-many elements, but there are $2^\lambda > \kappa$ paths through the tree. Each path determines a cut, almost all of which are Dedekind cuts, so we have constructed a linear order of size $\leq\kappa$ with $>\kappa$ many Dedekind cuts.